# spark-submit gives Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature

Tags: scala, console, executable-jar, spark-submit

I wrote a program in scala and created an executable JAR using the assembly instruction of sbt Now I have to upload and run it on my platform.

For building jar i have gone through

> File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Artifacts -> Click
>   green plus sign -> Jar -> From modules with dependencies..

I use the command:

```
spark-submit --class "ReadCSVwithnull" Scala.jar
```

but I get an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid
>   signature file d igest for Manifest main attributes at
>   sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVeri
>   fier.java:284)
>           at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier
>   .java:238)

mu version are InteliJ -2018.3.1
spark 2.3.2
scala 2.11.8
sbt version: sbt 1.2.7

Comment: Three things. First, I would suggest you to build the _assembly_ **JAR** by yourself using **SBT**, with the [`sbt-assembly` _plugin_](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly). IDEs are great, but I would leave the build job to a build tool - Second, make sure you mark any **Spark** _dependency_ as `Provided` & that you excluded **Scala** from the _assembly_ **JAR** in your _build.sbt_ file. You should never include your own **Spark** and **Scala**, because your cluster will already have them - Third and most important, use the same version of **Scala** that **Spark** uses. `2.11.8`.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the signature files inside the Manifest worked for me. 
Use command

```
zip -d Scala.jar 'META-INF/*.RSA' 'META-INF/*.DSA' 'META-INF/*.SF'
```